# Best way to check if two variables are correlated

Tags: correlation, agreement-statistics, calibration

(a) I have two variables that I am looking at: Visceral fat levels using MRI, and the visceral fat rating as shown by bioelectrical impedance (BIA) scales. The units for these two variables are different, and the sample size for each is close to 100. For each individual, there will be a single measurement using the MRI and another measurement with the BIA scale.

The MRI is the gold standard, so what I am trying to find is whether the visceral fat ratings given by BIA scales fluctuate in a similar manner to the corresponding MRI measurement. What I want to know is essentially whether the visceral fat ratings given by the BIA scales are accurate enough to give someone a good understanding of their visceral fat levels.

(b) I want to do the same thing, only across 3 different time points. So this time, I want to check whether the *change* between time points 1 and 2 for example, are comparable between the two methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of calibration problem, with an (expensive, presumably) goldstandard measurement and another cheaper measurement. What would I do? I will name the variables `Gold` and `Cheap`.

Plot Gold versus Cheap.  Plot the error `Gold - Cheap` against `Cheap`. Is this plot linear? Is the local mean (and local variance) of the error approximately constant? Or is there curvature in the plot?

Then calculate a regression of `Gold` on `Cheap` (if there is curvature in the plot above, you could represent `Cheap` via splines). If the constant term (Intercept) is approximately zero, there is no systematical bias. If the slope is close to zero, the bias is approximately independent of `Cheap`.

Just the correlation between `Cheap` and `Gold` is **not** a good measure, since it can be close to 1 with a large, but constant, bias.

**EDIT---answer to comments**

My language above was maybe imprecise, since *bias* has multiple meanings. What I tried to say is that correlation between `Cheap` and `Gold` can be large, even 1, in cases where `Cheap` is a very bad proxy for `Gold`. A simple example is `Cheap=Gold+100`. Here the correlation is 1, but using `Cheap` as a proxy for `Gold` gives a constant prediction error (bias) of 100. That is, correlation is a bad measure of agreement!

Comment: Regardless of the regression intercept being near 0 or large, correlation will always be biased?

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the relationship between correlation and bias? Thanks!

Comment: @develarist: See edits!

Comment: @ping: See edits: